# Adding a user to a VSTS team project requires to add him to the Team. Why is it not sufficient that he is added to a VSTS role?

Tags: azure-devops

We have the following setup in VSTS:

- Team Project: MyTeamProject
- AAD Group: VSTS_MyTeamProject_Contributors
- Team: MyTeamProjectTeam

This AAD group is added to the Contributors role of our MyTeamProject.

If we add a user, to the AAD group VSTS_MyTeamProject_Contributors, he will still not have access to the teamproject. 
We need to add him explicitly to the MyTeamProjectTeam.

Is this how this is supposed to work? It just seems to add additional administration overhead.

One way to solve this is by adding the AAD group VSTS_MyTeamProject_Contributors to the MyTeamProjectTeam.

But, we are not sure this is a correct/good way of working. Is there another solution?

Comment: Is the Contributors group a member of the Project Valid Users group?

Comment: You said he will still not have access to the teamproject, do you mean he can't access the team (MyTeamProjectTeam) or you mean he can't access MyTeamProject? Are there other teams in MyTeamProject?

Comment: What's the detail permission of Contributors group? What's the detail error when access MyTeamProject?